# Calling .Any() on Linq.IQueryable error: "The Linq expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Tags: c#, linq

My code

```
public bool hasID(){
  var IDs = db.users.where(x=>x.field == "test").Select(x=>x.ID);
  if(IDs.Any())
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Errors on the IDs.Any() line. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check for if(IDs == null)

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers - both of them worked. However db.user.any(x=x.field=="test") led me to find the base problem. I was using User.Identity in my comparison to x.field - and it was coming out null which was the root issue.

Comment: Vivek I didn't see your answer, this would have helped me as well. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Will u upvote, If I put this as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
public bool hasID(){
  return db.users.Any(x=>x.field == "test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public bool hasID(){
  var IDs = db.users.where(x=>x.field == "test").Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
  if(IDs.Any())
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```